# Xcode mysql management

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, macos

I want to connect to a mysql database from my Xcode project.
I'm familiar with c# programming and on windows I use EasyPhp for my mysql database, tho I'm new to objectC and Swift and Mac OS X database management.

I there a way to host a local database on a Mac like EasyPhp on Windows?

I've googled for similar projects and questions but could't find a relevant enough answer.

Comment: Xampp run on Mac Os X